# mongodb, copy all documents to collection

Tags: mongodb

collection_A is mapReduced result.

If I want to save { '11-8-12' : collection_A} in collection_B.

How can I save one collection to another collection, as one of elements?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can directly do that.

You have to manually build the document and save it to the database.

You can write this in JS and execute it with [db.eval(...)](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Server-side+Code+Execution#Server-sideCodeExecution-Using%7B%7Bdb.eval%28%29%7D%7D) so that data won't be transferred to the client, but this will convert integers to floats (the same problem you have with the mongodb shell).